# Find b and d in cubic equation

Tags: cubics

Find the $b$ and $d$ in equation:
$$
y= -x^3 + bx^2 + 4x + d
$$
The x-intercept is $(2,0)$ and it is point of inflection, but I don't know how to apply it to help solve the problem (point 2,0 is only given point).
I get to d= -4b but I got stuck...

Comment: What have you tried explicitly? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: You have two unknowns and two relations so just write out the two equations the relations imply.

Comment: Let's set $f(x) = -x^3 - bx + 4x -d$. Now, we have to pieces of information: 1) We know $f(2) = 0$. 2) There is a point of inflection at $x=2$. Can you reformulate the second point in mathematical terms? Hint: you'll need the derivative ...

Answer (score 1):

It is given to you that $(2,0)$ is a point of infliction. To use that information, differentiate the function twice

$$f(x) = -x^3+bx^2+4x-d$$

$$f'(x) = -3x^2+2bx+4$$

$$f''(x) = -6x+2b$$

At the point of infliction of a cubic, $f''(x)$ will be $0$.

$$-6(2)+2b=0$$

$$b=6$$

In the question you already have a relation between $b$ and $d$, use it to find $d$.